# How to convert UTC in LMT with field calculator in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, convert, datetime

I have GPS data in shape format in QGIS. But in my attribute table only the UTC time is given in the form of 01.01.2022 05:00. Is it possible to add a new column with the field calculator where I can convert the UTC column to my local mean time (LMT) column?

Comment: Are you asking, how to add/substract time to/from a given time value?

Comment: Yes, but with date and time. In my local mean time we are one hour past UTC. I'm searching for a formular adding this automatically in a new column. That means when UTC is first january 2022 23:00 (or 11 p.m.) I want in a new column the second january 2022 00:00 (12 p.m./midnight).